# Create constraint for stopping mass update to a table

Tags: postgresql, trigger, constraint, update, postgresql-9.3

I want to create a constraint so that if more than 5 rows in a table are getting updated with an `UPDATE` statement it should warn the user / block the query.

Comment: That's not possible with a constraint. A (statement level) trigger might be able to achieve something like that.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to implement this would be with a **trigger updating a temporary table** in parallel (that is only visible inside the same session).

[Create the temp table with `ON COMMIT DROP`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html), so that it lives for the duration of a transaction. This way, all **updates during the same transaction** count against the maximum.

Demo table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id serial, txt text)
```

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_foo_maxup()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
DECLARE
  _ct int;
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
   WHERE  relname = 'foo_maxup'
   AND    relnamespace = pg_my_temp_schema()
   AND    relkind = 'r'
   ) THEN

   UPDATE foo_maxup SET ct = ct + 1
   RETURNING ct INTO _ct;

   IF _ct > 5 THEN           -- your maximum here
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cannot update more than 5 rows in one transaction!';
   END IF;

ELSE
   CREATE TEMP TABLE foo_maxup ON COMMIT DROP AS
   SELECT 1 AS ct;
END IF;

RETURN NEW;

END
$func$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SET search_path = pg_temp;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER maxup
BEFORE UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_foo_maxup();
```

If you want a **maximum for the whole session**, just omit `ON COMMIT DROP`.

I added `SET search_path = pg_temp` to the function definition to prevent mischief with the `search_path`. This trigger only sees temporary tables in its `search_path`. That's why `pg_catalog.pg_class` has to be table-qualified.

[**-> SQLfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1628f/1).

Comment: That is a pretty nifty idea with the temp table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: My first impulse was a statement level trigger, too. But after some consideration I found this to be safe and cheap for a small maximum.